# Celery CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE doesn't work when I run a worker

Tags: python, celery

I want to run some workers in `topic` mode, so I change the `CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE` setting.

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'interesting_exchange'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'
```

When I want to public messages to a clean rabbitmq (assume producer started before consumer), like `simple_task.apply_async(args=[1, 2, 3])`, it declared fine: `interesting_exchange` declared as topic mode.

But when I want to run a worker from a clean rabbitmq (assume consumer started before producer), like `celery worker -A celery_app.app`, `interesting_exchange` declared as direct mode.

Do I need to specify other options? Or it's just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known Celery issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5772) and the [fix](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/5773) has already been merged. Upgrading to Celery 4.4 should solve the problem.